Python webcrawl bot doesn't get all page content
I'm trying to write a python bot to crawl this website "https://2e.aonprd.com/Search.aspx?q=reaper's lancet"
(the query is just an example one, I'm having the bot go over many item names and try to get their link).
items = items_database.find()
options = Options()
#options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--width=1200")
options.add_argument("--height=600")
options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36     (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3")
#firefox_options.add_argument("--headless")  # Runs Firefox in headless mode


service = Service(GeckoDriverManager().install())

for item in items:
    if item['name'] is None:
        print('Item with no name! Continuing.')
        continue

search_url = 'https://2e.aonprd.com/Search.aspx?q={}'.format(item['name'])
print('Finding item. Link is ' + search_url)

# Initialize the WebDriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=service, options=options)
driver.get(search_url)

# Get the page source and close the driver
time.sleep(5)
page_source = driver.page_source
driver.quit()

# Parse the page source with BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'html.parser')

# Find all <a> tags in the HTML
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    href = link.get('href')
    text = link.text
    if text != item['name']:
        continue
    
    # Print the href and text
    print(f"Link: {href}, Text: {text}")

`
Above is my code. How I get the list of items is not important, as I know that part works. For some reason, even after trying to sleep for a bit, it does not actually load the search results. If I run the browser without headless mode, it will open a window and display all the contents PERFECTLY. I'm confused as to why the page_source variable comes up with a lot of missing pieces, including missing the entire actual results div, which is just empty in the variable even though on the page that is opened it is fine.
Is there some javascript issue going on? I've also tried using things like this:
ol_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'ol.fill-width-with-padding.limit-width.results-list.item-gap-small')))

# Find all <a> tags within the <ol> element
a_tags = ol_element.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'a')

# Iterate through the found <a> tags and do something with them
for a_tag in a_tags:
    print(a_tag.text)  # Example action: print the href attribute of each <a> tag

which just gives me the error:
Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\repo\nethys_crawl_script.py", line 62, in <module> ol_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until( ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\repo\.venv\Lib\site-    packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 105, in until raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: Stacktrace: RemoteError@chrome://remote/content/shared/RemoteError.sys.mjs:8:8 WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:192:5 NoSuchElementError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:510:5 dom.find/</<@chrome://remote/content/shared/DOM.sys.mjs:136:16
I am not sure what to do at this point. Is this a common error with javascript heavy websites?
